# Strategies for Asset Allocation Considering Different Kinds of Tax Advantaged Accounts

Tags: united-states, retirement

What are some strategies for asset allocation across taxable and tax-advantaged accounts?

I have:

- A Defined Benefit Pension Plan (not really relevant to this question)
- A pre-tax supplemental retirement plan with many options (TIAA-CREF)
- A Roth IRA with many options (Vanguard)
- Taxable investments (Vanguard)

I'm comfortable with my overall mix of US and international stock and bond funds and cash.

I'm about 10 years from retirement and making maximum contributions to the tax-advantaged accounts.

I understand the general retirement strategies of spending down the taxable accounts first, trying to take only RMD's from the supplemental retirement account as long as possible, and withdrawing from the Roth IRA after other accounts.

My question: How should different classes of assets be allocated in the different accounts at different points in time?

e.g. Should I currently put the riskier investments (e.g. stocks) preferentially in the Roth IRA (where they'll have more time to grow) and less risky assets in a taxable account?  What about the relative advantages of investment income versus capital gains on the taxable account?

Comment: The Defined Benefit Pension Plan can be considered a cash portion, of your retirement funds. You will be able to count on $x per year.

Comment: See https://ofdollarsanddata.com/the-best-way-to-organize-your-assets/